# What size ratchets do I need to assemble some new equipment?

Tags: tools, powertools, self-assembly-furniture

I recently purchased a power rack and various other bits and pieces for the home gym. In the [instruction manual](http://www.samsfitness.com.au/pdf/P-PR-Powertec-Power-Rack.pdf) the nuts and bolts on the hardware list state the following sizes:

1/2" × 3 - 1/2"
1/2" × 16t

I'm about to go and purchase a ratchet set toolbox, but don't want to spend a ridiculous amount; on top of that I need to make sure I buy the correct sized ratchet set.

What should I be looking for? I was in Screwfix earlier and the lady didn't know what I was on about; then I took a trip to Halfords and didn't know what to buy. I have a bag full of tools but can't access it at the moment.

I was thinking of getting some pieces to add onto the drill and use the drill to tighten the bolts, but I don't want to round them off.

Comment: It didn't come with a crappy bit of metal that the manufacturer calls a "wrench"?

Comment: @Tester101: I think I have a drawer full of those little Allen wrenches somewhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So it has a bolt that is 3 1/2" long with a 1/2" head, and a 1/2" nut...

You're going to need a 1/2" socket and/or wrench, and/or a couple [adjustable spanners](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjustable_spanner). Looks like you're in the UK; so you probably use metric, So you'll need an 1/2" imperial socket and/or wrench, and/or a couple [adjustable spanners](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjustable_spanner).

Comment: You can still get imperial sockets and spanners in the UK :) You need to as there's no such thing as a 12.7mm one (unless it's a badly made 12mm or 13mm one).

Comment: Thanks, @ChrisF.  Didn't know if imperial sockets were used elsewhere in the world. HAHA, guess you're right about the 12.7mm wrench.  Just did the math, and didn't even think about wrench sizes.

Comment: Engineer here with my opinion: The US just needs to give in already. [ಠ_ಠ](http://joerotondidesign.com/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2010/02/20100203-metric.jpg)

Comment: @Doresoom I agree... but then again, 16 on-center sounds better than 406.4mm OC. We'd have to rebuild everything! Future generations would look at everything we've built, and say "WTF! didn't these guys have tape mesures!?"

Comment: Found my old bag of tools, unfortunately the adjustable wrenches were missing so I purchased a set of 3 for £7. Found 2 ratchets and several attachments.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you've already received the home gym (and aren't just reading the manual online), why not just take one nut and bolt of each size with you to the hardware store to make sure you're getting the right tool?